# No internet when connected to openvpn server

Tags: openvpn

I want to connect my laptop to my office's network using an openvpn connection with the server located on a Cisco RV320 router. After a lot of struggle I managed to establish the VPN connection and a I can ping devices on my office's lan through VPN. What I can't do is accesing Internet when connected to VPN. I know i could use split tunnel but i want to access Internet through VPN because there are some hosts that accepts connection only from my office's public IP. What can I do?

Comment: What operating system is your laptop running ( windows / linux )? Normally you can choose which route ( VPN or direct ) to use in openVPN or the client you are using.

Comment: But the openVPN server has to be configured to allow that. Also read [the howto](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect) for this.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. I'm testing on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. The openVpn server is a cisco RV320 router and when I configurated the server I chose full tunnel. In the howto there is a rule to add in iptables, but I understand that work when you use linux server. Anyway, I need it to work on a windows machine too. Do you have any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Haven't used openVPN on Windows for years. So not really sure, but I thought you can set that in the openVPN client.

Comment: How would you do it on linux? That command in the howto is intended to be used on the client or server?

Comment: Not really sure, redirect-gateway should be the client option. But you also have to configure the openVPN router to allow routing.

Comment: Whatever is performing NAT in your network needs to be configured to NAT for clients in your OpenVPN subnet.